# Контейнерные классы

Tags: java

Какой класс или классы является набор объектов, которые вручную разложены в очень важном порядке, и этот порядок нужно сохранить.

Comment: Почитайте про коллекции и Map. Вот доки, там вы можете увидеть структуру: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html (коллекции), https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html (Map).

Comment: SortedMap? LinkedList?

Comment: В том числе. Я же правильно понял вопрос?

Comment: Сам вопрос непонятный. SortedMap сортирует автоматически, как я понимаю.

Comment: https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/5.9.php . Мануальчик: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html

Comment: Вы бы не могли бы ответить конкретно на вопрос?

Comment: Какой вопрос? Лучше чем в мануале я не объясню.

Comment: ArrayList
LinkedList
HashSet
HashMap
TreeSet
SortedSet
TreeMap
HashList
Какие из них?

Comment: Они все являются наборами объектов, которые разложены в очень важном порядке. Просто порядок определяется разными способами, способы хранения в памяти различаются и тд. Достаточно массивная тема, в комментариях не объяснить. Пока могу посоветовать только искать информацию о реализациях(хотя бы основополагающих) интерфейсов Collection и Map.

Comment: Не обязательно в комментарии, можно в ответе.)))

Comment: Я лучше вам сайт посоветую: https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/5.1.php . Еще в доках все ясно изложено. Слишком много информации - не готов ответ писать(скорее, просто копи пастить из других источников - например из доков).